# Angular Validators.pattern Regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

Pattern `[^%&\\\'+"]` does not work with angular `Validators.pattern(regex)`.

I've tested the pattern `[^%&\\\'+"]` using https://regexr.com/ and it should match all characters EXCEPT the following: **%&\'+"** but it did not.

It should match

> all characters EXCEPT %&\'+"

Here is a sample string to check:

> abcABC`~1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|[{]};:'",<.>/?

In regex creator sites, it **works** but in Angular it does not.

Comment: are you adding `g` flag? `Validators.pattern(/[^%&\\\'+"]/g)`

Comment: @guijob no, there is no flag. Should i add? what is that for?

Comment: @guijob I did add and still doesn't work.

Comment: @VicCebedo what your angular version ?

Comment: @kobi version @angular/core: 4.3.1

Comment: @VicCebedo Did you try this one [^%&\\'+"]

Comment: Try `Validators.pattern(/^[^%&\\'+"]*$/)`

Comment: If it does not work, please share a JS fiddle.